# Cannot login to my Apple ID in System Settings

Tags: macos, apple-id, settings, system-settings, ventura

I'm using MacBook Air M1 (2020).

After I have updated it to macOS Ventura, it has been showing me a message saying that I need to log in again to my Apple ID in System Settings. I have tried to find the log in button there but failed. So, I have just tried to log out and log in.

However, every time after logging out and in, I try to log in to my Apple ID and it fails without a message.

How can I log in to my Apple ID in System Settings in Ventura?

(My Apple ID works well on any other platforms including iPhone and iPad.)

I have already restarted my MBA several times. Do I need to clean up the whole device, and re-download the OS? Is there any other solution?